# EF Code First Existing Table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have an **Asset** table and a **Client** table.
When a client creates an **Asset** there is a foreign key created for the **Client**.

Now I need to add a **CustomMetadata** to the **Assets**. First I created a table called **ClientMetadata** which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CompanyMetadata](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [TypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [DefaultValue] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Values] [text] NULL,
    [Order] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Filter] [bit] NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientMetadata]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([ClientId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Clients] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClientMetadata]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([TypeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ClientMetadataTypes] ([Id])
GO
```

So what I need now, is a table called CustomMetadata which has a reference to **Assets** and to **ClientMetadata** but I am unsure how to set it up, because it will need it's own value which EF needs to pull in when it gets  the **Assets**.

So **Assets** will have a navigation property like

```
public virtual ICollection<CustomMetadata> Metadata { get; set; }
```

And the **CustomMetadata** would look like this:

```
public partial class ClientMetadata
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool Filter { get; set; }

    public virtual ClientMetadataTypes ClientMetadataTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual Asset Asset { get; set; }
}
```

Where **Value** would be the actual value stored the **Asset**.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I hope it all makes sense.

Cheers,

/r3plica

Comment: If you already have an existing db and you just want to get the poco classes and the navigation configuration you can use this http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838 it saved me a lot of time

Comment: You're mixing up names, CompanyMetadata, ClientMetadata, ClientMetadataTypes, CustomMetadata ... confusing.